# No rights to view file as member of root group

Tags: linux, centos7

I am in the group `root` who owns a file and all the directories above. Why do I have no access to this file? CentOS 7

```
$ ls /etc/systemd/system | grep parts.service

ls: cannot access /etc/systemd/system/parts.service: Permission denied
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? parts.service
```

With SUDO:

```
$ sudo ls /etc/systemd/system | grep parts.service

-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root  563 Feb 13 09:59 parts.service
```

Checking for an ACL:

```
$ sudo getfacl /etc/systemd/system/parts.service
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: etc/systemd/system/parts.service
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::rw-
```

My groups:

```
$ groups
root wheel docker poweruser
```

Parent directories

```
drwxr-xr-x  155 root root 12288 Jul 17 09:04 etc/
drwxr-xr-x    4 root root      151 Nov 11  2019 systemd/
drw-rw-r--   19 root root  4096 Jun 19 18:14 system/
```

Answer (score 0):

sudo is used to verify that you are the user with which you are logged. you can access root files with your user, but you have to tell your PC that you want to acces files from the root group